# PdfPTable cell width

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I'm using `iTextSharp` to create PDFs in my application. However I have to recreate a table, where I have to set the size for a very small column. Below is the picture that shows the size I want to set the column:
[image]

When the rest of the table creation all is well, **I can't set this width**.

**Code:**

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 82.0f;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Com a assinatura autógrafa, o signatário desta Auto-declaração garante ter cumprido estas condições:", fontetexto));
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
cell.PaddingTop = 10f;
cell.Colspan = 2;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("1. ");
table.AddCell("Os óleos e gorduras vegetais velhos fornecidos são biomassa conforme o Decreto de biomassa.");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this code

```
PdfPTable table =  new PdfPTable(new float[] { 30f, 400f });
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

Comment: `the file was corrupted`. I think the error is `float[] widths`

Comment: Ok, works like this: `PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 30f, 400f });`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with much less efforts if you use XmlParser rather then the normal HtmlParser

```
var document = new Document();
var workStream = new MemoryStream(); // or you can use fileStream also.
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
 XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, stream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Check this nuget [MvcRazorToPdf](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRazorToPdf/) ,I found this better then RazorPDF

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.TotalWidth = 500;
table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 30f, 400f });

PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell();

c1.AddElement(new Phrase("first column"));
c1.AddElement(new Phrase("second column"));

table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { c1, c2 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @IntellectWizard help me to reach a solution.

`float[] widths = new float[] { 100f, 4000f }; // Code @IntellectWizard`

gives a corrupted file, then i try:

`PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 30f, 400f });`

This works!