# Itext, table width changes when splitted in new page

Tags: java, itext

I'm using `iText 5.3.4` with `Eclipse Kepler`. I have a bill table, normally it would not have more than one page, but for testing pourposes i've been checking it's behaviour and I'm facing a weird problem, table `width` changes when page changes:

[image: table width changes!]

My table definition:

```
PdfPTable tableFactura = new PdfPTable(4);
tableFactura.setWidthPercentage(80f);
tableFactura.setWidths(new int[]{55, 15, 15, 15});
tableFactura.setKeepTogether(false);
tableFactura.setHeaderRows(1);
```

If i define different width the problem still persist, but with another dimensions.

The table is filled in a `for-loop` with `PdfCell` and `Paragraph` inside, nothing complex:

```
// ONE of the CELLS of each line
cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(factura.get("descripcion_linea" + numeroLinea), tinyNormal));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setPaddingLeft(10f);
cell.setPaddingTop(5f);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
tableFactura.addCell(cell);
```

My document is standard, `Document document = new Document();`, i tried including also `document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);` but nothing changes. As you can see in the image, i've also tried without content in cells.

Any idea why is this happening?

**UPDATE1:** as suggested by @Bruno here is [Link To File](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f37968fc150f24331aac1c76b6a5177420150331151020/511a1e).

**UPDATE2:** [here](http://ideone.com/77RHIQ) is a piece of code "simulating" what I am doing, but issue is **NOT** happening

Comment: This looks like the print margin for double sided print (Mirror Margin), when the margins are flipped depending on the page being even or odd.

Comment: if you look a the image, you can see issue is happening in both sides...

Comment: What happens if you add a third page? Does the width grow more or does it have the same size as the second page?

Comment: Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), you should not expect an answer, even if you open a bounty on it. We just can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ian2thedv if there are more pages size stays same as 2nd page...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i've tried to reproduce outside the main program, but error does not appear, that's why I started bounty, because I know is not problem of `iText` is something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what... I expect somebody has found same issue and knows what can be wrong in my background....

Comment: Maybe if you share your PDF so that we can take a look inside. For instance: we don't know if the page got smaller or if the table got bigger (I assume the latter). It's also odd to me that the table doesn't have a bottom border. Also what happens if you remove the `setKeepTogether()`. I think we should delete this method from iText. That could very well be the culprit. Why is it there? It's not documented anywhere is it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie updated question with pdf file. Also nothing changes when `setKeepTogether(false)` line is deleted... I thought it was useful when a table gets splitted in 2 pages to mantain a continuity, it does not work for that? You suggest to not use it?

Comment: We no longer use it.

Comment: @JordiCastilla is it possible for you to post all your code so that i can run it on my local pc?

Comment: @kucing_terbang if you read all comments you will find: *i've tried to reproduce outside the main program, but error does not appear, that's why I started bounty, because I know is not problem of iText*

Comment: @JordiCastilla oh yes i have read all the comments but I'm just wondering if there is some thing in your code that you didn't post like probably you somehow change the width?

Comment: [check this... might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094190/pdfptable-cell-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally solved it. Thanks to [@BrunoLowagie](http://www.lowagie.com/) and [@Fahim Parkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828/fahim-parkar).

Will make a quick explanation of all my modifications according to all suggestions:

**First** of all and according [@Bruno](http://www.lowagie.com/) comments, first I deleted unused method `PdfPTable::setKeepTogether(boolean);`.

**Second**, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094190/pdfptable-cell-width), posted by [@Fahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828/fahim-parkar) (thanks!). We can force table's size by [PdfPTable::setLockedWitdth(boolean)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setLockedWidth(boolean)) **before** setting the `TotalWidth`.

```
PdfPTable tableFactura = new PdfPTable(4);
tableFactura.setLockedWidth(true);
tableFactura.setTotalWidth(425f);
tableFactura.setWidths(new int[]{55, 15, 15, 15});
```

This allows table to have same size in all pages... but not all done, to avoid weird behaviour in the last row and in page breaks (with single or multiple pages) I must include:

```
tableFactura.setSkipLastFooter(true);
```

**Third:** Now table limits are correct, just need to correct page breaks, for that I defined footer rows.

```
tableFactura.setHeaderRows(2);
tableFactura.setFooterRows(1);
```

NOTE: according [PdfPTable::setFooterRows()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setFooterRows(int)):

> Sets the number of rows to be used for the footer. The number of footer rows are subtracted from the header rows. So in this example row 1 will be footer and row 2 will be header.

**Fourth:** simply adjusting margins, borders and paddings to my needs I get the exact result I desired.

TA DA! :)

Answer (score 1):

I never used iText, but I think the problem is at below lines.

```
tableFactura.setWidthPercentage(80f);
tableFactura.setWidths(new int[]{55, 15, 15, 15});
```

Can you try two cases below and let me know how it goes?

### Case 1 : Setting width 100%

```
tableFactura.setWidthPercentage(100f);
tableFactura.setWidths(new int[]{55, 15, 15, 15});
```

### Case 2 : Setting widths as per 80%

```
tableFactura.setWidthPercentage(80f);
tableFactura.setWidths(new int[]{50, 10, 10, 10});
```

If not, check this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094190/pdfptable-cell-width) might help.

Comment: Can you just go with case 1 and see both pages? still both pages giving this error?

Comment: different size, but same error. *For if the flys I tested it again*, size of first page table is bigger than expected and second page goes out of margins...

Comment: fakim, [your link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094190/pdfptable-cell-width) gives me the clue to fix the problem... B-D if you're agree I will modify your answer with the fix and so I can give to you bounty

Comment: @JordiCastilla : what edit you make? Update answer and put what change made it right...

Comment: i could not update your question with all my answer, edits would be rejected by SO rules, so, I put your comment at the end of your answer, give to you the bounty and answered my own question with all important info I used to solve it... Imagine, the little edit I've done (with explaining comment about why this change) has one downvote... so is the best way i found to explain what happened and why you deserve bounty ;)